# Why function name as variable?

Tags: javascript

While studying [`Element.scrollHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight) i failed to understand 2 things. The code example is as described below:

```
function checkReading () {
  if (checkReading.read) {
    return;
  }
  checkReading.read = this.scrollHeight - Math.round(this.scrollTop) === this.clientHeight;
  document.registration.accept.disabled = document.getElementById("nextstep").disabled = !checkReading.read;
  checkReading.noticeBox.textContent = checkReading.read ? "Thank you." : "Please, scroll and read the following text.";
}

onload = () => {
  const oToBeRead = document.getElementById("rules");
  checkReading.noticeBox = document.createElement("span");
  document.registration.accept.checked = false;
  checkReading.noticeBox.id = "notice";
  oToBeRead.parentNode.insertBefore(checkReading.noticeBox, oToBeRead);
  oToBeRead.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createElement("br"), oToBeRead);
  oToBeRead.onscroll = checkReading;
  checkReading.call(oToBeRead);
}
```

1. Why they have used **checkReading**(which is a function name) as object/variable?
2. I tried to remove **checkReading** and used **oToBeRead** object as `this`, so when i used `this.reading = this.scrollHeight - Match.round(this.scrollTop)===this.clientHeight`
   the function **checkReading** is converted to constructor function,
   **why so?**

here's my updated code where the function is converting to constructor function:

```
function checkReading () {
  if (checkReading.read) {
    return;
  }
  this.read = this.scrollHeight - Math.round(this.scrollTop) === this.clientHeight;
  document.registration.accept.disabled = document.getElementById("nextstep").disabled = !this.read;
  this.noticeBox.textContent = checkReading.read ? "Thank you." : "Please, scroll and read the following text.";
}

onload = () => {
  const oToBeRead = document.getElementById("rules");
  oToBeRead.noticeBox = document.createElement("span");
  document.registration.accept.checked = false;
  oToBeRead.noticeBox.id = "notice";
  oToBeRead.parentNode.insertBefore(checkReading.noticeBox, oToBeRead);
  oToBeRead.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createElement("br"), oToBeRead);
  oToBeRead.onscroll = checkReading;
  checkReading.call(oToBeRead);
}
```

[image: This is how the function is converted to constructor function and then quokka is giving tip to change it to class declaration]

This picture is showing how the function is converted to constructor function and then quokka is giving tip to change it to class declaration

Comment: This is really unusual, not to say bad, code. Looks like poor man's namespacing to avoid some extra global variables.

Comment: "*the function checkReading is converted to constructor function*" - no it isn't. It's still an ordinary function that's called as a method on the `oToBeRead` element. It's a constructor only when you call it as `new checkReading()`.

Comment: @bergi well the code is available in MDN. Also try my updated code in VSCode you'll see its converted to constructor function. For confirmation use Quokka.js on the js code and you'll see the fix.

Comment: It's because it has `this` which JS assumes makes it a constructor that references to instance properties. But instead, the code's approach is to use `this` by setting the context with `function.call(context)`

Comment: @Brother58697 even i came to this conclusion previously and tried to justify it, but haven't found anything about it yet. So currently its just a theory but there's nothing to be sure about it. If you find something let me know.

Comment: @Brother58697 what about using the function name as variable, if you see they using `checkReading.read` or `checkReading.noticeBox.textContent`??

 what i believe is that function name is same as naming a variable or namespace, so maybe that's why they have used it in similar manner. But i'm still unsure.

Comment: From what I see, they want to add a variable to `cheakReading` while also having it get called several times `onscroll`, to do that, they added a property to the function. But they don't need to do that. They save `noticeBox` as a variable in `checkReading`, and return an inner function for the `onscroll`

Comment: If you want, I can show you a very concise and reusable way to pull this off

Comment: Where exactly on MDN can this code be found?

Comment: @Pointy It's in the [example section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight#examples) of the page that is linked in the first sentence of the question.

Comment: @ManojKS091 What do you mean by "*in VSCode you'll see its converted to constructor function*"? Does vs code autocorrect something in the code?

Comment: @Bergi ah. Well, it's weird code, that's for sure. Properties on functions are not always bad of course, but used like in this example that "read" flag is kind-of like a global variable. If it were to be used for two portions of the page, it wouldn't work (I don't think).

Comment: @Bergi I shared the screenshot of the tip, hope it will be clear now.

Comment: @Brother58697 Dunno why they used it, even if they want to call variables several times they can define a variable within `checkReading` function. And it will do what we want.

Comment: @Pointy well its just about variable scope. The scope of the variable defined within a function can't be used outside that function. Properties on function will make the function have its own properties that wont be inherited to other instances, so why they have defined properties on function?? because according to our goal there wont be any instantiation or inheritance . Also i dont think we define function properties(the properties that should be on function itself), within function declaration.

Comment: It's certainly possible to add or modify properties on the function object from within the function itself when it is called.  In this case, it is very questionable. No matter how many times the function is called for handling the task (remembering if something has been "read"), once the flag is set then it will always be set, so if it is used for two parts of the page, once one has been read, all of them will look as if they have been read. It is not a good example for MDN.